# How to use do while loops

Tags: java, do-while

I am trying to put a password onto this section of code, I am trying to use a do while loop but it carries on looping.

Can you please show me where my errors are? The password I am using is `1234`.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class cipherprac
{                    
  static int choice = 0;
  public static String msg;
  public static int password = 1234;
  public static int response = 0;

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the message");
    response = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the password"));
    do
    {
      char enc;
      String encmsg = "";
      int len = msg.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) 
      {
        char cur = msg.charAt(i);
        int val = (int) cur;
        val = val - 30;
        enc = (char) val;
        encmsg = encmsg + enc;  
        msg = encmsg;    
      }
    }
    while(response == password) ;      

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " " + msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to loop at all? Can you explain, in words, what this piece of code is supposed to do?

Comment: The code is for encryption, I am wanting to encrypt a message, which works but I want the user to enter a password to encrypt the data so only certain people can encrypt and decrypt messages. If the user enters the wrong password I want the code to loop until the correct password is entered.

Comment: Are you interested in doing this in the best fashion possible or are you trying to complete an assignment? I ask this because there are much stronger and easier methods for encrypting data with a password in Java. It's important to know if you have any constraints.

Comment: Its for an assignment unfortunately, I have to incorporate a do while loop into my system. I still need to use an if else statement if that would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change the `response` (nor `password`) in your code, so if you set it to `1234` then it will be looping for ever.

Comment: Now I understand why it keeps looping, how would you make the program only loop once if the correct password is entered, and continue if the  wrong password is entered? Its for an assignment so I have to use a do while loop.

Comment: So formulating your assignment - you need to **do** /something/ and repeat it **while** entered password is **not** correct. Do...while loop always does things in do{...} at least one time. So if the condition in while(...) won't be true after executing code in do {...}, it will stop. If the condition in while(...) will be true, it will continue. So your condition needs to be like `while (properPassword != passwordGiven)`. BTW if my answer helped you, you can upvote it, and even accept it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh okay so the code should look something like this         </b>  do
         {
            response = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the password"));
            if (password != response)
            {       
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered the wrong password");
            }     
         }
         
         while(password != response);

Answer (score 1):

`response = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the password"));` is the last time you set "response", so it will be that forever, hence the infinite loop.

This seems to be some sort of custom encryption? Anyway, you'd want to do something like:

```
do
{
    ...
} 
while(response == password && "Certain condition isn't met");
```

This way it will end the loop if for some reason the user input changes OR if it is done with your process.

Answer (score 0):

Well you do not change the value of your `password` or `response` variable inside the loop. So how is the loop supposed to stop?

Your loop will run once and at the end check whether condition for continuing is met. If yes, it will start the next iteration of the loop code block. If you do not change anything inside the loop which has an effect on the loop's condition, it will run once (if the condition evaluates to false) or until you kill the program (if the condition evaluates to true).

As for the normal work of a loop, here you can find a good explanation with examples in many languages (including Java): [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues:

- Not updating response inside the loop
- While condition loops again if successful, I think it should try again on unsuccessful password if I understand correctly.

Do you want to keep trying until your password is correct?

In this case, your while condition should be true when they are not equal, so that if it is not successful, you keep trying.

In your case, if your response is not 1234, it will not try, and if it is, it will loop forever.

Ideally for a do while loop:

```
set condition value before loop
do{
    // do some work
    // update condition value
}while(condition);
```